# Javascript: Order of operands in comparison operator

Tags: javascript, performance, comparison

Is there a specific reason why I have seen many people writing

```
if(1 === a) {...}
```

instead of

```
if(a === 1) {...}
```

I had given an answer in which I wrote something like `Array === obj.constructor` which is when someone asked me that he has often seen people writing like this instead of `obj.constructor === Array`.

So does it really matter which way I use?

Comment: could be since in `x===y` x is evaluated first and if x is NaN false is returned ASAP  as per spec http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison

Comment: It's a placebo practice: people believe it will solve their most important development problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [yoda conditions](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/yoda):

> Yoda conditions are so named because the literal value of the condition comes first while the variable comes second. For example, the following is a Yoda condition:

```
if ("red" === color) {
    // ...
}
```

> This is called a Yoda condition because it reads as, “red is the color”, similar to the way the Star Wars character Yoda speaks. Compare to the other way of arranging the operands:

```
if (color === "red") {
    // ...
}
```

> This typically reads, “color is red”, which is arguably a more natural way to describe the comparison.
>
> Proponents of Yoda conditions highlight that it is impossible to mistakenly use = instead of == because you cannot assign to a literal value. Doing so will cause a syntax error and you will be informed of the mistake early on. This practice was therefore very common in early programming where tools were not yet available.
>
> Opponents of Yoda conditions point out that tooling has made us better programmers because tools will catch the mistaken use of = instead of == (ESLint will catch this for you). Therefore, they argue, the utility of the pattern doesn’t outweigh the readability hit the code takes while using Yoda conditions.

Comment: Interesting. The force was strong with this one.