# Does it matter on which side a value goes in a JavaScript expression?

Tags: javascript, expression

Let's say I have a variable x and I want to check if x equals string 'y'.

Is there any difference if I did either of:

- x  === 'y'
- 'y' ===  x

Or let's say that I want to check if y is bigger than x:

- x < y
- y > x

The difference can be anything, in terms of how the code is executed, and which is preferable, not only in terms of performance, if any, but also readability.

Comment: maybe you have a look to [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logical if difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334353/logical-if-difference) and [Javascript: Order of operands in comparison operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035875) and [Checking for null - what order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983573)

Comment: Usually it doesn't matter, unless either side is another expression, the left-handed side expression will always execute first.